# Why LD_LIBRARY_PATH is BAD and the correct way to load dynamic libraries

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, shared-libraries

So, I have a program that runs with OpenBlas and I want to compile it. The linking process looks like this:

```
gcc -o prog prog.o -O3 -I/opt/OpenBLAS/include -L/opt/OpenBLAS/lib -lopenblas
```

So far so good. If I remove the `-L` option, I get an error in the linking process

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopenblas
```

With the `-L`everything links without errors. However, when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
./prog: error while loading shared libraries: libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If I set the env variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/opt/OpenBlas/lib` I can run the program, but many sources like http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html consider this to be a bad practice and I can understand almost all the reasoning. The other method mentioned in the article (modify the ld configuration) is also considered to be somewhat a bad practice. Finally, you could just add a symlink to the library in `/usr/lib`. A big problem with the last two methods is that you need sudo access.

So my question is how can I compile and run a program linked to a shared library that is not located in a default path (`/usr/lib`) without using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`and sudo access. In the article they say that you can just 'write' in the binary where to look for shared libraries but I do not know how to do that (the `-L` flag does not seem to be doing it). I would appreciate if anyone could explain this matter, since I've been looking everywhere and I'm very confused (some references seem to suggest that the flag `-L' should do it but I does not work for me). Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use -rpath to set the runtime library search path

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add the path to the runtime library search path.

```
gcc -Wl,-rpath=/opt/OpenBlas/lib ...
```

What the `-L` option does at link time, the `-rpath` option does at run time.

Comment: This is probably the answer the OP is looking for, though it's also bad because it builds the path into the executable, requiring the executable to be recompiled to relocate the library. So you should basically understand all the solutions, why they're all bad, and then pick the one that's the least bad for your use case. ;)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: You can relocate the library without recompiling, you just have to relocate it to somewhere else in the runtime search path... which is the same choice you have if you don't use `-rpath`.  And you can always use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if you really want to move the library somewhere else.  Sorry, I'm not seeing the drawbacks, except the possibility that `-rpath` is a bit *noisy* if you copy the binary to another system.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: You can also modify the `rpath` without recompiling, using the `chrpath` tool.  You can't do this on OS X unless the new `rpath` is shorter, but alas, nothing is perfect.

Comment: Thanks! This was indeed the answer I was looking for. However, I cannot find the -rpath option in the documentation https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary I was also wondering what are the -Wl options for and if they are necessary.

Comment: The "-Wl," is to pass the rpath option to the linker, "ld" when it is creating the exectuable.

Answer (score 8):

On linux, it is also possible to use $ORIGIN in rpath to mean the directory path to the application and build a relative rpath from there. You would then move the library to a known relative path to the binary.

```
gcc -o prog prog.o -O3 -I/opt/OpenBLAS/include -Wl,-rpath=\$ORIGIN/lib -L/opt/OpenBLAS/lib -lopenblas
```

You can also use the full path to the libary, and it will be linked in:

```
gcc -o prog prog.o -O3 -I/opt/OpenBLAS/include /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas.so
```

If you run "ldd" on the executable, you should see the full path encoded.

Comment: You will need to quote `$ORIGIN`, or the shell will expand it (probably to an empty string). `'-Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN/lib'` will work.