# How to avoid using LD_LIBRARY_PATH when building a SimpleAmqpClient project?

Tags: c++, ld, rabbitmq-c

I have the following in a file `test.cpp`:

```
#include <SimpleAmqpClient/SimpleAmqpClient.h>

int main() {
    AmqpClient::Channel::ptr_t connection = AmqpClient::Channel::Create("localhost");
}
```

I can compile and run it like this without any issues:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -o test -l SimpleAmqpClient
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ ./test
```

But, I would like to do so without having to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

I have tried adding `-L /usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu` to no avail:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -o test -l SimpleAmqpClient -L /usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu
$ ./test
./test: error while loading shared libraries: librabbitmq.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What is a good way to avoid having to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Thanks!

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25918462/1870232)

Comment: @P0W - in my case this is different, since I don't actually need "-L" during compilation.